# How to accept gmail emails without enabling "allow less secure apps". PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I have a free hosting account at `000webhost`. I have configured `PHPMailer` to send a message to me in the `mail` as soon as someone fills out the feedback form. Messages do not come if the `gmail` function `allow less secure apps` is disabled.
How to accept `gmail` emails without enabling `allow less secure apps`. This is my main mail, and I would not like to disable protection on it. It's not here for beauty, is it?) After searching the Internet, I could not find a similar solution. Seems disabling `allow less secure apps` suits many. So maybe there is a way to make my hosting account trusted?

Comment: No, disabling less secure apps is the only way. If you don't like this, set up a separate Gmail account just for your application to send from. They are free, after all...

Comment: Then why letters from other `mailboxes/websites` come without problems? Does it depend on the `ssl` certificate? It seems even on the free plan `000webhost` has `ssl`.

Comment: I believe _allow less secure apps_ option is relevant in the context of IMAP protocol.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you're saying, due to the lack of code to clarify it. Are you trying to use Gmail to send the email via SMTP? Only Gmail has the "less secure apps" feature. What do you mean by letters from other mailboxes coming without problems? You mean coming into your Gmail? That wouldn't be relevant to what your PHP application is doing.

Comment: Buy a domain for $5.00. Go to rackspace.com and by a business email account for $2.99 to use with this domain. Congratulations. You now have an email account that you pay for with much higher limits. Gmail is not mean to be used by programmers for business with clients. Gmail will blacklist anyone who appears to be doing stuff “out of the ordinary”. Using OAUTH will mitigate some of that, but getting mail scopes now requires a lot of assurances that you’re not doing something weird and potentially external validation of your platform for security and privacy.

Comment: @ADyson, I meant why email from other websites come without problems. I received an answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @suchislife, Now I understand, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the naysayers, this is entirely possible, and it doesn't involve IMAP.

To be clear, the "allow less secure apps" option *only* applies to *sending* email *from* your gmail account. It has nothing to do with you receiving messages from other people, or how they receive messages sent from you.

Gmail (and others) offers an SMTP authentication mechanism called XOAUTH2, which is, as you might expect, based on OAuth 2.0. If you use this mechanism, you do not need to enable "less secure apps". PHPMailer supports this mechanism, and provides  code example showing you how to use it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps). However, that only shows how to use the auth credentials, not how to get them, which, being OAuth, is a confusing and unpleasant experience. Fortunately there is [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) (which should always be the first place you look before asking questions anyway) and [an example script](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/get_oauth_token.php) that helps you get the tokens you need. I'm not going to reproduce them here because it just makes more work for me as a maintainer.

The approach is broadly:

- Define an OAuth app within your Google account
- Use the supplied script to perform an authentication procedure (requires that you have a functioning HTTP server)
- Take the credentials from that process and drop them into the PHPMailer sending example.
- Send email as usual.

Comment: I used this library for the first time. I read the documentation but didn't immediately understand what oauth2 is for. It seems to me that not everyone knows about it, because the only advice I found in many answers (including the `000webhost` administrator's answer) is to enable `allow less secure apps`. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Indeed, Google doesn’t make it clear that what they mean by *not* allowing less secure apps is that you **must** use OAuth.